# find $T(t), N(t),$ and $K$ of given $r(t)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$r(t)=(t+\cos (t))\hat{i}+(1-\sin (t))\hat{j}$

I tried to find $T(t)$ but I hit a roadblock. I know the equations to plug everything in but I need some help in simplifying things.

I've gotten r'(t)=(1-sint)i+(-cost)j

I ended up with $T(t)=\large \frac{r'(t)}{\|\sqrt{2-2\sin (t)}\|}$

Comment: A trigonometric identity simplifies your denominator.  Also, you can show your attempt to compute the derivative in the numerator.

Comment: @GEdgar could you tell me which trig identity because I've been searching and I can't find one that fits